# Storing duplicate values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

What's the correct way to deal with inserting records with common values? e.g. a university field, or state etc?

Does mongo apply any sort of value-based hashing to optimize space, or should I do that manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating a hashed index on the duplicated field will result in the field being stored in hashed form. Mongo does not apply this index automatically, but it should optimize space if you do it manually. [This page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/) in the MongoDB documentation shows you how to do it and I found that [this article](https://scalegrid.io/blog/the-case-for-mongodb-hashed-indexes/) explained it nicely as well.

Comment: For answers that contain links please include some of the relevant details in the answer :)